# AWS Auto Scale: on scaledown, is it possible to notify the dying machine to retrieve logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[In this document in the AWS KDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/RetrievingLogsFromAutoScalingInstances.html), they outline how to have a lifecycle hook to retrieve logs from a soon-to-be-terminated machine. However, I see no reason at all why the terminated machine can't handle the task all on its own.

Is it possible to have the AutoScale group send a lifecycle hook notification to the machine that is being descaled? That is, tell THAT machine "hey, you're going down" without having to create some sort of external web service tell the machine in question?

Something on the order of the "user data" field in the LaunchConfiguration would be ideal. The machine in question can be trusted to not keep itself in the `terminate:wait` state.

Answer (score 0):

This would be best done using the meta-data service for AWS EC2. I'm not sure there are enough use cases to convince anyone this is necessary. What are the benefits you see over life-cycle hooks?